# Is there a USB-C PoE adapter for iPad Pro?

Tags: ipad, usb, power, ethernet

Is there a dongle which plugs into the USB-C port on the iPad Pro that accepts Power over Ethernet (PoE) so when PoE is available there’s no need to plug an additional USB-C cable to provide power to the device?

I see that starting this year Apple is selling a [Belkin adapter for the lightning port](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HMJU2ZM/A/belkin-ethernet-power-adapter-with-lightning-connector?fnode=91&fs=f%3Dbelkin%26fh%3D4588%252B3233) which provides this, but I don't see any offerings for USB-C

I'm looking for an always-on kiosk implementation where Ethernet is preferred and more robust than Wi-Fi.

Comment: How _portable_ of a solution are you looking for? Will the iPad be mounted, e.g., point of sale system?

Comment: @atwalsh it's a kiosk implementation. Added detail to op.

Comment: I've edited your post a little, but one thing worth clarifying is whether you actually need the PoE functionality because that's how you want your device powered, or whether you're also able to just have an adaptor that provides ethernet data functionality while also providing a USB-C port with power pass through?

Comment: maybe better use some custom hardware for kiosk? based on raspberry pi and linux, will be cost effective and you can find anti vandal screens for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D199JQP) to turn 802.3at POE+ into data and USB-C power, then use a short USB-C cable and a short CAT6 cable to immediately patch into one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XY3Z4MH) (haven't personally tested this adapter but it should work **in theory**).  Not ideal since it requires multiple adapters, but a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Coolgear](https://www.coolgear.com/product-category/usb-c-products/usb-c-poe) list a selection of USB-C PoE devices.

I haven't used any myself, and I don't think they ship outside the US if that's relevant.